# What is a sepset in a probabilistic graphical model?

Tags: terminology, causality, graphical-model, definition

The terminology sepset is used quite often in the Probabilistic graphical models and causality. What does it mean and what is its relevance ?

Answer (score 4):

The term sepset is used in connection with cluster graphs. A cluster graph  is a graph with nodes $C$ including a subset of variables $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$.

A **sepset** $S_{ij}$ is the subset of variables between nodes $C_i$ and $C_j$ that are in the intersection of the scopes of both nodes (scope simply means the list of variables node $C$ depends on. I.e., $S_{ij} \subseteq (Scope(C_i) \bigcap Scope(C_j)).$

If $C_i = \phi(A, B, C)$ and $C_j = \phi(B, C, D)$, then possible sepsets are:

- $S_{ij}^1 = \{\}$ - this means there is no edge between $C_i, C_j$
- $S_{ij}^2 = \{B\}$
- $S_{ij}^3 = \{C\}$
- $S_{ij}^4 = \{B,C\}$

The relevance of sepsets is that they determine e.g. in [belief propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation) whether a node $C_i$ sends a message to $C_j$ about a given variable (they only send a message containing information about a variable if it is in $S_{ij}$).

Comment: Would you please define "scope of a node". It isn't clear how it differs from a neighbourhood.

Comment: The scope of the node is the set of variables included in that node. E.g. if a node $X$ is described by potential $\phi(A, B)$, then the scope is $\{A,B\}$. Whereas the neighborhood is the set of the nodes connected to $X$.

Comment: In the above definition, do $C_i$, $C_j$ need to be connected via an edge in the cluster graph? Or does it hold for any two arbitrary nodes?
I am asking this in context of a definition I found in *Probabilistic Graphical Models by Koller and Friedman* (section 4.5.3). There clique trees were being discussed, and the connecting edge seems to be a requirement (although not clear from the sentence); quoting - 
**"Let $C_i,C_j$ be two cliques in the tree that are directly connected by an edge; we define $S_{i,j}=C_i \cap C_j$ to be a *sepset* between $C_i$ and $C_j$."**

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty: as you can see in the example I provided above, having no edge is also possible.